# How to document self-declared types in haddock?

Tags: haskell

I have a function with the signature `Own_type1 -> String -> Own_type2 -> IO ()` and want that I can explain my own types and that in the eventual documentation it is properly linked up etc. etc.

How can I achieve this when using Haddock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You link to your own types in just the same way as you link to other types (see [section 3.8.6](http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html) in the Haddock documentation).

Comment: Thanks for the Link that solved my problem. I had overseen that since I did not know what "Markup" means.